# Kubernetes not allowing to delete a deployment - the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I get  `the server could not find the requested resource` error when I try to delete a deployment, event when it is listed.

```
D:\cmd
λ kubectl -n gdpr-tr get all
NAME                                              READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/scv-turkey-iys-integration-6dd784689f-z6hqc   0/1       InvalidImageName   0          1m
pod/scv-turkey-iys-integration-79c4d7ffcd-pwmq4   0/1       ErrImagePull       0          6m

NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/scv-turkey-iys-integration   1         2         1            0           1h

NAME                                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.apps/scv-turkey-iys-integration-6998c5b5f9   0         0         0         1h
replicaset.apps/scv-turkey-iys-integration-6dd784689f   1         1         0         34m
replicaset.apps/scv-turkey-iys-integration-79c4d7ffcd   1         1         0         25m

D:\cmd
λ kubectl -n gdpr-tr delete deployment.apps/scv-turkey-iys-integration
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of below commands to delete the deployment but make sure kubectl client and kubernetes api server version matches
Because in `1.16` version deployments is migrated to `apps/v1` from `extensions/v1beta1`. So if you have a kubectl client which is of older version it will not be able to find the deployment in `apps` api version.

```
kubectl -n gdpr-tr delete deployment scv-turkey-iys-integration 
kubectl -n gdpr-tr delete deployments/scv-turkey-iys-integration
```

Comment: I have added an explanation of the cause of the error